# Умножение выбора селекта и данных из инпута

Tags: javascript, html

Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такую вещь, есть 1 селект и 1 инпут туда number, при выборе чего то из селекта и ввода числа в инпут, напр.при выборе банана  происходит умножение цены банана на количество, а результат выводится чуть ниже

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="Banan">Банан</option>
    <option value="Apple">Яблоко</option>
    <option value="Pear">Груша</option>
    <option value="Grapes">Виноград</option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" value="amount" min="1" max="50" step="1" placeholder="Укажите предположительное количество (кг)">
</form>
<div>Здесь результат умножения</div>
```

Comment: Сформулируйте правильно вопрос, ничего не понятно! Где цена, где количество?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не расстраивать учительницу математики и не умножать килограммы на бананы, надо все-таки добавить цену к каждой опции, а затем уже умножать.

```js
var fruit = document.getElementById('fruit'),
  weight = document.getElementById('weight'),
  result = document.getElementById('result');

fruit.addEventListener('change', function() {
  listener(fruit);
});

weight.addEventListener('change', function() {
  listener(fruit);
});

function listener(elem) {
  var price = elem.querySelector(':checked').getAttribute('data-price'),
    kg = weight.value;

  result.innerHTML = multiply(price, kg);
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="fruit">
    <option value="Banan" data-price="100" selected>Банан</option>
    <option value="Apple" data-price="150">Яблоко</option>
    <option value="Pear" data-price="200">Груша</option>
    <option value="Grapes" data-price="250">Виноград</option>
  </select>

  <input id="weight" type="number" value="amount" min="1" max="50" step="1" placeholder="Укажите предположительное количество (кг)">
</form>
<div id="result">Здесь результат умножения</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function mkChange(item) {
  var kg = document.getElementById('kg').value;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = item.value * kg;
};

function mkChange1(item) {
  var select = document.getElementById("mk");
  var fruct = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = item.value * fruct;
};
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mk" onchange="mkChange(this);">
    <option value="10">Банан - 10p</option>
    <option value="20">Яблоко - 20p</option>
    <option value="30">Груша - 30p</option>
    <option value="40">Виноград - 40p</option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" id="kg" value="0" min="1" max="50" step="1" placeholder="Укажите предположительное количество (кг)" onkeyup="mkChange1(this);" onchange="mkChange1(this);">
</form>
<div>Здесь результат умножения: --- <span id="total">00</span>p</div>
```

Comment: и тут то что надо спс!

Answer (score 1):

```js
calculate = function() {
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  var price = e.options[e.selectedIndex].attributes['data-price'].value;
  var amount = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
  var fullprice = parseInt(price) * parseInt(amount);
  document.getElementById("results").innerText = fullprice;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select onchange=calculate()>
    <option value="Banan" data-price="2">Банан</option>
    <option value="Apple" data-price="3">Яблоко</option>
    <option value="Pear" data-price="4">Груша</option>
    <option value="Grapes" data-price="5">Виноград</option>
  </select>

  <input onchange=calculate() type="number" value="amount" min="1" max="50" step="1" placeholder="Укажите предположительное количество (кг)">
</form>
<div id="results">Здесь результат умножения</div>
```

Comment: то что надо спс!